# Error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to open an csv file but i'm having an error `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte`. What i did is :

```
df = pd.read_csv("covidrisks.csv")
```

Comment: Try passing `encoding='latin-1'`

Answer (score 1):

I had to save the file under `csv utf-8` and that solved my problem